Losing /var root directory for apache2 on vps hostinger using ubuntu 22.04 os
I'm facing issue while working with Hostinger VPS  every time auto deleting /var root directory on VPS for apache2 server after reinstalling Ubuntu 22.04 even after rebooting the VPS on the Hostinger platform. It works for a few minutes and then the whole directory is deleted.
I'm using apache2 server configuration file which in the future will be working with Flask and React js. I want to know why I'm losing the /var directory after reinstalling Ubuntu 22.04 on Hostinger VPS. I can access the /var directory for few minutes, then I'm facing a no such file or directory error.

Welcome to AskUbuntu. Unfortunately there is not enough information here to work with. Could you provide further details, such as what software is being installed or what configuration settings are being set when you prepare an Ubuntu 22.04 server? This may make it possible for someone to identify which non-standard item is resulting in the /var directory being deleted

I'm using apache2 server configuration file in future will be working with flask and react js. Here I want to know why I'm loosing /var directory after reinstalling ubuntu 22.04 os on vps hostinger. I can access /var directory for few minutes then facing error "no such file or directory".
